# When can I delete data provided to QImage?

Tags: multithreading, qt, delete-operator, qimage

I create `QImage` like this:

```
unsigned char* const rawImage = (unsigned char*)std::malloc(WIDTH*HEIGHT*3);
for ( ... ) {
    // Populate the image here
}
QImage img(rawImage, WIDTH, HEIGHT, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

I then post signal with that image to another thread (GUI thread in particular):

```
emit imageRendered(img);
```

I thought I can delete the data afterwards:

```
delete rawImage;
```

But this causes segmentation errors in the other thread. If I do not delete the raw image, the program consumes all available memory. How to make safe copy of QImage so that I can delete my raw data?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is pretty specific on the subject:

> The buffer **must remain valid throughout the life** of the QImage and all
>   copies that have not been modified or otherwise detached from the
>   original buffer. The image does not delete the buffer at destruction.
>   You can provide a function pointer **cleanupFunction** along with an extra
>   pointer **cleanupInfo** that will be called when the last copy is
>   destroyed.

You'd use the following constructor:

```
QImage::QImage(uchar *data, int width, int height, Format format, QImageCleanupFunction cleanupFunction = Q_NULLPTR, void *cleanupInfo = Q_NULLPTR)
```

Pretty much what you have safe for the actual clean up pointers.

As for making an actual copy of the data, keeping in mind `QImage` uses CoW, calling a non-const function might do the trick (haven't tested it myself though):

```
uchar *QImage::bits()
```

> Note that QImage uses implicit data sharing. This function performs a
>   deep copy of the shared pixel data, thus ensuring that this QImage is
>   the only one using the current return value.

You might also try simply `auto newImage = img.copy();`

Comment: I believe the best way to handle this is to do `QImage imageCopy = image.copy()` followed by `imageCopy.detach()` to force a deep copy of the image based on an external buffer. Then simply work with the copy.